# URL Action to email filtered list of data on button click

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a Tableau dashboard where the user should be able to:
(i) Edits filters
(ii) Click a button to email the filtered list

I have (i) handled. On (ii) I am having trouble creating a button that when clicked emails the list of data. I know how to create the URL action to email; but the problem is that the button doesn't have access to the data list (because as far as I know the only way to create a button is to make it a separate sheet).

Would love any advice to achieve this email functionality.

Dashboard :

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vck8u.png)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality to email from a button is not built into Tableau Dashboards.

[Dashboard Extensions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboard_extensions.htm) might help in this situation, though. They were recently introduced as a way to help people do custom things. They allow for a 'widget' of your own design to be placed on your dashboard and operate with the data on the dashboard. Presumably being able to send in an email would be possible.

[Here](https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/) are some examples.

(URL Actions are purely designed to take a user to a website.)

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a URL action using mailto:: instead of http:: or can use the [JavaScript API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm) to access the data to programmatically generate a mail message. A URL action is easier.